# Cordova Plugin: Unable to retrieve path to picture

Tags: android, cordova, android-camera

Searching for a solution to the following problem for a while and can't seem to find any solutions. Any help is welcome.

The camera plugin of cordova returns the following error when trying to access a picture using the camera.

Unable to retrieve path to picture!

I tried FILE_URI and DATA_URL.

I use cordova version 5.0.0 and cordova-plugin-camera.

The following path fails e.g.

```
/storage/emulated/0/Download/horse-331746_640.jpg
```

The following path functions e.g.

```
/storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-2015019-WA0000.JPG
```

My Function:

```
function captureNow(bGallery){

    if(bGallery === true){
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onCapturePhoto, cameraOnFail, {
            quality: 100,
            correctOrientation: 1,
            targetWidth: 500,
            targetHeight: 500,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
        });
    } else {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onCapturePhoto, cameraOnFail, {
            quality: 100,
            correctOrientation: 1,
            targetWidth: 500,
            targetHeight: 500,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Updating the camera plugin and Cordova CLI did not help

Comment: It happened to me when I picked GIF image from the photo library

Answer (score 0):

The fail message *Unable to retrieve path to picture!* is caused by hardcoded requirement in the plugin that image selected from gallery must have either `image/jpeg` or `image/png` mime type (see [cordova-plugin-camera: CameraLauncher.java](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/4.0.2/src/android/CameraLauncher.java#L707-L710))

While you are getting this message for JPEG image, I'd say that:

- even that image has png extension, it's mime type isn't image/jpeg (image is corrupted or it's extension have been renamed)
- you are using plugin version lower than 4.0.2 which could return this message for other scenarios